# spreading data in R - allowing multiple values per cell

Tags: r

With these data

```
d <- data.frame(time=1:5, side=c("r","r","r","l","l"), val = c(1,2,1,2,1))
d

  time side val
1    1    r   1
2    2    r   2
3    3    r   1
4    4    l   2
5    5    l   1
```

We can spread to a tidy dataframe like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>% spread(side,val)
```

Which gives:

```
  time  l  r
1    1 NA  1
2    2 NA  2
3    3 NA  1
4    4  2 NA
5    5  1 NA
```

But say we have more than one `val` for a given time/side. For example:

```
d <- data.frame(time=c(1:5,5), side=c("r","r","r","l","l","l"), val = c(1,2,1,2,1,2))

 time side val
1    1    r   1
2    2    r   2
3    3    r   1
4    4    l   2
5    5    l   1
6    5    l   2
```

Now this won't work because of duplicated values:

```
d %>% spread(side,val)

Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (5, 6)
```

Is there an efficient way to force this behavior (or alternative). The output would be e.g.

```
  time  l      r
1    1 NA      1
2    2 NA      2
3    3 NA      1
4    4  2     NA
5    5  1, 2  NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data.table`/`reshape2` equivalent of `tidyr::spread` is `dcast`.  It has a more complicated syntax than `spread`, but it's more flexible.  To accomplish your task we can use the below chunk.

We use the formula to 'spread' `side` by `time` (filling with the values in the `val` column), provide the `fill` value of `NA`, and specify we want to `list` elements together when aggregation is needed per value of `time`.

```
library(data.table)

d <- data.table(time=c(1:5,5), 
                side=c("r","r","r","l","l","l"), 
                val = c(1,2,1,2,1,2))


data.table::dcast(d, time ~ side, 
                  value.var='val',
                  fill=NA,  
                  fun.aggregate=list)
#OUTPUT

#    time   l  r
# 1:    1  NA  1
# 2:    2  NA  2
# 3:    3  NA  1
# 4:    4   2 NA
# 5:    5 1,2 NA
```